# No value property in select/option when using Html.DropDownListFor with System.Linq.Enumerable

Tags: c#, html, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Razor page with the following code for creating a drop down of 1 to 31 days of month. The dropdown is rendering correctly in the browser, but the HTML output is missing the value property (except for the first option, which is being added manually).

How can I get it to render the value property?

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Day, new SelectList(System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(1, 31)), string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Rendered Output:

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" id="Day" name="Day">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
    <option>24</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>26</option>
    <option>27</option>
    <option>28</option>
    <option>29</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>31</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @RyanWilson `System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(z => new SelectListItem(z.ToString(), z.ToString()).ToList()` is not compiling. I changed it to `Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(t => new SelectListItem(t.ToString(), t.ToString())).ToList();`and now it's showing the `type` of the select list item in the dropdown https://imgur.com/a/SYVpF9P

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

**Controller:**

`ViewBag.Days = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(t => new { Value = t, Text = t });`

**View:**

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Day, new SelectList(ViewBag.Days, "Value", "Text"), string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })`